Django login form error: `BaseForm.__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'my_username'
I created a simple login form in Django, but I got this error when I tried to run the server:

I searched a lot but found nothing. I read many articles here and on GitHub.
This is my form code and views code.

I made it with HTML and it worked, but in the Django project, I created a file named form.py and wrote the code. Once I tried running the server, I got this error.


I tried searching in the documentation of Django.

Can anyone help, please?

Please don't post images of your code.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.  Login_Page has two fields, my_username and my_password, not usrname or password.

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

You don't pass data as named parameters to the form, you pass it as a dictionary-like object. In fact request.POST (and request.GET), etc. are already dictionary-like objects:
def my_login(request):
    user_data = LoginPage(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # …
But you can not use user_data.save(): you use a Form, not a ModelForm, so it has no .save() method. You can check if the user_data.is_valid(), and if so, access user_data.cleaned_data['my_username] to obtain the data entered for that field.


Note: Functions are normally written in snake_case, not PascalCase, therefore it is
advisable to rename your function to my_login, not myLogin.



Note: Usually a Form or a ModelForm ends with a …Form suffix,
to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
working with a form. Therefore it might be better to use LoginPageForm instead of
Login_Page.

